# Filling leading space with Zero

Tags: sas

I have account numbers and the leading zero's have been dropped. For example 01234567 is instead recorded as 1234567. How can I easily put all the zero's back in? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Z` format to print a number with leading zeros; you'd want `z8.` to print 8 digits with leading zeros as necessary.

A bigger problem is that your data is probably the wrong type. It's generally a bad idea to store things like phone numbers and account numbers as numerics. You should only store something as a numeric if you plan to do arithmetic with it. Anything else should be a character variable, even if it only consists of the digits 0-9.

If possible, create the variable as a character variable from the start. That will preserve the leading zeros and also prevent multiple possible headaches in the future.